# Gatsby: CSS by className only sometimes works

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby

I thought I should be able use `className` to apply CSS to any React Component or Element.

For example, this works:

```
<span className="testi"><h1>Testing</h1></span>
<style jsx>{`.testi{ margin: 100; }`}</style>
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
<Img className="testi" fluid={fluid}/>
<style jsx>{`.testi{ margin: 100; }`}</style>
```

When I inspect the HTML that is produced by Gatsby, I can see that the `<div>` created by the `<Img>` has the correct class, but despite this the CSS is not applied. Why does this happen?

Edit: this is not a duplicate. The linked "duplicate" proposes to modify the Component in question. `Img` is part of Gatsby, it's not my component, so I can't reasonably modify it. I should be able to apply CSS to it without modifying it.

Comment: It could just be your css is being overwritten by pre specified one, or your css is not being loaded into the page? FWIW, `Img` seems to accept a `style` props that'll takes a custom style object `{color: 'red', ...etc}`. Perhaps that's simpler, if you're only looking to pass in custom style?

Comment: Yeah, I actually ended up using the style prop. It's just ugly because I end up with copypasta CSS.